# What does OmitThisParameter from ES5 definitions do in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I found this type in the ES5 definitions for TypeScript, and was wondering what it does because the simple description is kind of vague.

```js
/**
 * Removes the 'this' parameter from a function type.
 */
type OmitThisParameter<T> = unknown extends ThisParameterType<T> ? T : T extends (...args: infer A) => infer R ? (...args: A) => R : T;
```

[source code](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/26655db1dd04d93217002ac87f950aba812c53eb/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L326)

The description implies that `this` is a type, but when you look at the code it's not clear exactly what they mean by it.

I have searched the Microsoft documentation for TypeScript, but there appears to be no references to how this is used or why.

Here is an example of source code where I've seen it used.

```js
export class Example {
   funcRef: OmitThisParameter<()=> void>;
   func() { }
   constructor() { this.funcRef = this.func.bind(this); }
}
```

There doesn't appear *to me* that there is any static type advantages here. The usage of `funcRef` seems to have no restrictions. Could it be that this prevents `funcRef` from being used as a constructor function?

If I make the following changes the source code compiles without any issues.

```js
export class Example {
   funcRef: () => void;
   func() { }
   constructor() { this.funcRef = this.func.bind(this); }
}
```

Isn't this type identical to an arrow function, but we don't declare types for arrow functions.

So I'm looking for an answer that explains what type advantages this has, and why we should use this type, because I very *rarely* see it used.

Can you give a source code example that would cause TypeScript to raise a type warning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [`this` parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#this-parameters) is a pseudo-parameter that you put first in a function signature, and it says that inside the function, the `this` context will have the defined type.  It makes the function more specific, in that both the implementation of the function and any callers of the function will treat it as if the function is a method of a particular type.

For example:

```
function addX(this: { x: number }, y: number): number {
  return this.x + y;
}
```

The function `addX()` must be bound to an object with a numeric `x` property to be called successfully.  The implementation doesn't complain about `this.x` because of this.  That prevents you from calling it in a standalone way:

```
addX(10); // error!  you can't call this function by itself
```

Instead, you have to bind it correctly... here's one way:

```
const val = {
  x: 123,
  addX: addX
};
val.addX(10); // okay, you're calling it as a method of type {x: number}
```

And if you bind it to the wrong type of thing you get an error also:

```
const badVal = {
  x: "whoopsie",
  addX: addX
};
badVal.addX(10); // error! string is not a number, can't do this
```

---

So a function with a declared `this` parameter is less forgiving about where it's used.  If you have a function with a `this` parameter and would like to call it in an unapproved way, you can use the `OmitThisParameter<>` utility type:

```
const unsafeAddX: OmitThisParameter<typeof addX> = addX; // okay
unsafeAddX(10); // no error (but kablooey at runtime, "this is undefined")
```

I wouldn't necessarily *recommend* doing this, but just like there are times when [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) are useful, there are probably times when ignoring a `this` context restriction is useful.

---

So, backing up to this:

```
  funcRef: OmitThisParameter<() => void>; //
```

That evaluates to precisely `() => void`.  The type `() => void` has no `this` parameter, so omitting it does nothing.  There's really no reason in the world to use the type `OmitThisParameter<() => void>`, and I suspect it's a mistake.

Looking at that class and squinting I can imagine doing something like this:

```
export class Example {
  funcRef: OmitThisParameter<Example["func"]>;
  func(this: Example) {}
  constructor() {
    this.funcRef = this.func.bind(this);
  }
}
```

I've added the `this` restriction to the `func()` method (you'd think `this` contexts on actual class methods would automatically happen, but [they don't](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6018#issuecomment-207479337).  Slows down the compiler too much, I guess.), and then made the type of `funcRef` such that it is the same type as `func` with the restriction lifted.  And that causes the following behavior:

```
const x = new Example();
const func = x.func;
func(); // error! bad this context
const funcRef = x.funcRef;
funcRef(); // okay
```

Oh well, hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwCaoBoAooAsYDOAXIgN6IAeJYIAtgEYCmATogL4A0iAntXU8wCUfBizIBYAFCJEzRlBDMkeQgDoKiANQ8A3FLZSpaTFgCMABkE7EAehuIWzOMwCEM7nBCIIyMAHIob2QAG2DEFQJEUEhYBER6bkQYKAJGYOBDSQgEAkCANxDEAF4JaUoSUwAmAGYOKRljDBJG-T1JAuDVRrNLaztEOABrZG4uDxA-OSDQmDAAcyTA5EjkRFp5XDhUAeBw7gAHRjIqRBpRZgNJKWywXPi0ADVCktJ68sQAIgB3Tbh9ghgjA+dTKjWa6AwrSk9EeIS6EJ6Vls9kczjcuWYswWhFOcCWp34LC4Pn8gVQcHC+AImRud3ABGQwEYAEEISQAPK0ZIAFSpAAVkMxkOsoCwADxQA6MOC7RoAPmKKAhfXsQxGUnpjJZCIsSP6YApqNYWHoIECw3owTgcEYiWQgWY4Fg6y4HwiSUi4FQjGAs0YqA+gkyjAo+2cgQgwWWkQAohRhftgkdXmVohAAEo+jlcqC8wgCoUi8VxhNJgDaHzTHwAunK2jI0zgqSQS7RE4xBGRLjJaVBHdBnFhOymZDIIqo05ndiVx2nVPRZqgm4QrG9Lpde5RFWBGF9EK320O2pu04qKBPwBA2o29SjmE5XPdtu6bqKKFBrjlApOfWeL5Ap2vS8pyPZEBmGbgpCAA)

Comment: Thank you so much! This all made sense to me, and doing `Example["func"]` is also very clever. I can see now why the example is kind of meaningless, and why I couldn't understand it.